# Did Time in the Matrix Pass in Real Time?

Tags: the-matrix

There are some scenes in *The Matrix* that seem like they take a long time in the Matrix, but not as long in real life.  Do people in the Matrix experience events in real time, or is the Matrix time speeded up (or even slowed down)?

Comment: I think the time in the Matrix passes in real time. But the agents and the One have the ability to slow or speed time in small pockets. If you have seen the Animatrix, you may have noticed that glitches in the Matrix slows down the time.

Comment: @KenSuvy - Good point. In a short story, that if I remember correctly was an extra in The Matrix DVD, the Machines were able to compress simulation time. They packed a whole (rewarding) life in a matter of a man's last dying moments in recognition of his help.

Comment: By "scenes", are you referring to the bullet time scenes or full sequences of events?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, operators (outside The Matrix) can telephone with people inside The Matrix. Anything other than a negligible drift would be obvious to the operator, the person in The Matrix and the audience (i.e. you).

In addition, The Matrix merely fakes the sensory input to your brain. Unless you're The One, your brain works exactly the same in The Matrix than in "the real world" -- you can *perform* fancy stuff inside The Matrix, if you're trained, but your cognitive abilities are the same.

Last but not least: Neo's physical age matches his residual image -- he aged at the same speed in his prison as his physical body did.

Edit: The reason that some things look extremely slow in The Matrix is completely out-of-universe for theatric effect.

Answer (score 5):

Matrix is a real-time simulation. Telephone conversations between those within the Matrix and those still in the hoverships take place without any noticeable pitch difference or time shift to either party. Neo's very first phone conversation with Morpheus lasts minutes, but Neo is able to follow Morpheus' instructions to the second to evade the agents searching the cubicles. If there was a temporal shear, timing would have been off the more time passed.

Comment: That's an excellent point -- and we have seen the conversations from both sides, so even after seeing Neo talk to him in real-time, when we saw the other side (from in the ship), there was no time delay issue either.

Comment: Unless there is Matrix-within-Matrix and their clock rates are synchronized.

Answer (score 3):

The passage of time in the Matrix is relative to each individual; the point made in Goliath (comic S1,C1).  Years could go by in a manner of minutes and time could also repeat in an infinite loop.  In the end, the protagonist experienced a lifetime of events in 57 minutes.